# Filter df based on list column containing at least an element in a list (intersection of 2 lists)

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have:

```
mylist = ["test", "new"]
df = pd.DataFrame([[["test", "whatever"]], [["tes", "test_in"]], [["new2", "new1"]]], columns=["a"])
df

    a
0   [test, whatever]
1   [tes, test_in]
2   [new2, new1]
```

And I want to filter and get only the rows that have at least one value in mylist:

```
    a
0   [test, whatever]
```

I can't do:
`df.query("a.str.contains('|'.join(@mylist))", engine='python')`
 because then I get partial matches.

I was thinking something like:

```
 df[df.apply(lambda x: set(x['a']) & set(mylist), axis=1)]
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, only convert sets to bool for empty sets to `False`, else `True`:

```
df = df[df['a'].apply(lambda x: bool(set(x) & set(mylist)))]
print (df)
                  a
0  [test, whatever]
```

Alternative:

```
df = df[[bool(set(x) & set(mylist)) for x in df['a']]]
```

Or:

```
df = df[[bool(set(x).intersection(mylist)) for x in df['a']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check with `isin` after re-create your list columns

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.a.tolist()).isin(mylist).any(1)]
Out[23]: 
                  a
0  [test, whatever]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
mylist = ["test", "new"]
df = pd.DataFrame([[["test", "whatever"]], [["tes", "test_in"]], [["new2", "new1"]]], columns=["a"])
print(df)

    def func(x):
        for e in x[0]:
            if(e in mylist):
                return True
            else:
                continue
        return False

    df = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1), :]
    print(df)
```